# Covering electronic device with plastic film wrap

Tags: damage, conductivity, equipment

I hope someone can help here with an electronics issue I have.

I am currently shipping an electronics device, [an audio reel to reel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reel-to-reel_audio_tape_recording) to be exact. It was suggested that I wrap it in [plastic film wrap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0752JWW7L), which I did. As I was wrapping it I started getting small shocks (not painful, but constant). I didn't realize there is anti-static film wrap, which is what I probably should have bought. I am now worried that I might have damaged the device by using static plastic wrap. It has been removed for the time being.

I have to questions:

1. Is it critical that I use anti-static plastic film wrap when wrapping electronics?
2. Is it possible that I damaged my device?

This is an expensive piece of equipment, so I am freaking out here. If anyone has any insight it would be really appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you rebuild/repair the deck, are you just selling as used gear, etc?

Comment: Perhaps you should turn it on and test it to see if it works.  That seems like it would be more productive than worrying about whether it's damaged.

Comment: It was recently taken to a shop for repair. It still turns on. This is a complex machine so its hard to ensure that everything is working to full state, especially since I am not a pro when it comes to R2Rs. Hopefully everything is still good though. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Critical and a mandatory requirement for industrial, MIL, medical, telecom, etc.  Strongly recommended for home/amateur.
2. Certainly possible.  But most tape decks have a metal deck, internal chassis, and rear cover.  Plus, the older the deck is the more robust it will be against ESD (fewer IC's, generally lower circuit impedances, more metal shielding, etc.)